# c++ std::function, can be replaced by auto or not

Tags: c++11

suppose this is right:

```
std::function< void() > callback = std::bind( &Test::blah, test );
```

can I just do

```
auto callback = std::bind(&Test::blah, test)
```

?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `std::bind` is *unspecified* (§20.8.9.1.2), so you're basically forced to use `auto` with it. However, it returns a function object which can be stored in `std::function`, which allows the first line to work.

Comment: Furthermore, the object provided by `auto` will implement static dispatch but `std::function` always incurs an indirect function call. `auto` is the preferred, more efficient option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact all *three* of these could be used:

```
std::function< void() > callback1 = std::bind( &Test::blah, test );
auto callback2 = std::bind(&Test::blah, test);
auto callback3 = [=]() mutable {test.blah();};
```

My choice would be the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
struct f {
    virtual void func(auto a) = 0;
};
struct g {
    virtual void func(std::function<void()> a) = 0;
};
```

They are two totally different things, and sometimes you can use `auto` but often not. Only function-local variables can be reasonably declared as `auto` (and maybe polylambdas in C++14).

But for function-locals, `auto` is the superior choice. It's becoming an increasing trend for experts to eschew the use of explicitly typed local variables altogether in most circumstances.